# Cannot get EclipseLink to work under WebSphere 7

Tags: jpa, websphere, eclipselink

We have to transfer a web application that was running (relatively) fine under WebSphere 6.1 to WebSphere 7 (for now).

The application uses EclipseLink instead of the stock JPA support in WebSphere 7.

We had a message which suggested JPA 2.0 was not supported by WebSphere (ie it complained about the 2.0 related entries in the persistence.xml file) so we installed the feature pack for this.

We did not augment the existing profile (as it is normally used for another application and we didn't want to mess with it) and created new ones.

Now as far as I can tell WebSphere 6.1 also had a different JPA support but it was not causing any problems and now it looks like under WebSphere 7 the internal/stock JPA support is causing problems.

The error message I am currently getting is

```
[7/29/14 15:52:17:816 EDT] 0000001e JaxbUnmarshal E   CWWJP0040E: Incorrect syntax or error detected in the persistence.xml file in application: B2B-WebEAR-LATEST.0.ear, module: B2B-Web-LATEST.0.war, at line number: 10, column number: 13. The following associated error message occurred: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'provider'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":mapping-file, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":jar-file, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":class, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":exclude-unlisted-classes, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":shared-cache-mode, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":validation-mode, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence":properties}' is expected.
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:90)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:147)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:219)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:192)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:148)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JaxbPersistence20.<init>(JaxbPersistence20.java:107)
at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JaxbUnmarshaller.java:109)
at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPxmlInfo.extractPersistenceUnits(JPAPxmlInfo.java:132)
at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAScopeInfo.processPersistenceUnit(JPAScopeInfo.java:117)
at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAApplInfo.processModulePUs(JPAApplInfo.java:169)
at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAComponentImpl.startingDeployedModule(JPAComponentImpl.java:895)
at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAComponentImpl.stateChanged(JPAComponentImpl.java:748)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stateChanged(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1098)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectEvent(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1302)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.setState(DeployedModuleImpl.java:222)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:608)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:759)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1291)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5305)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5483)
at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1296)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2068)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:332)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:603)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:565)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1203)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:272)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1152)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:298)
at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1146)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:999)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:847)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:783)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1331)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1224)
at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:239)
at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:578)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:374)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.isclite.container.controller.InformationController.processForwardConfig(InformationController.java:218)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistence(WSCUrlFilter.java:970)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:504)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:325)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3994)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:277)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1049)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:643)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1660)
```

Our persistence.xml file, after adding declarations which were initially missing but WebSphere kept complaining about is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="b2b">

    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/b2bv</non-jta-data-source>
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <jar-file>cognosReportsLibrary-1.0.9-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar</jar-file>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <shared-cache-mode>DISABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode> 

    <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>

    <class>com.example.web.service.dto.DistributorTypeDTO</class>       
    <class>com.example.web.service.dto.MaintenanceInfoDTO</class>
    <class>com.example.web.service.dto.ContactSellDTO</class>
    <class>com.example.web.service.dto.ImportExportLogDTO</class>               
    <class>com.example.web.service.dto.NotificationDTO</class>

    <properties>
        <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->

        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables" />

        <!-- <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" /> -->
        <!-- <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables" /> -->

        <!-- Ref: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Foundation/Logging#Using_Log4J -->
        <!-- <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" /> -->
        <!-- custom SessionLog implementation to use apache commons logging 1.1 API (so log4J) -->
        <!-- <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="org.eclipse.persistence.logging.CommonsLoggingSessionLog"/> -->
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

I know that the library that provides JPA support is weirdly named and I cannot do much about this as I am not, normally, part of that application development team, I was just borrowed temporarily to that team. That library was MAVENized and contains multiple libraries which is something I am not a fan of because of dependencies issues it can cause (I know it can fix them as well but not the way we use them).

I am not a JPA guru, far from it, actually I had never heard about it until recently. I had heard of Hibernate (but not actually used it) which implements it though but this is not what we are using here...

What I know about this application is that it uses JPA annotations and not mapping files so I cannot provide the "mapping-file" entry it is complaining about.

We are currently using WebSphere 7.0.0.33 which was "augmented" with a feature pack to provide JPA 2.0 support and EclipseLink 2.3.2.

Does anybody know what's can be done to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It complains because persistence.xml violates [schema](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd). Element *provider* should occur before element *non-jta-data-source*:

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<non-jta-data-source>jdbc/b2bv</non-jta-data-source>
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I never thought they had actually enforced an order for the elements and it wasn't enforced under WebSphere 6.1. I actually had a ticket opened with IBM about this issue (which had reached level 2) and your answer was right on the mark, theirs ...